# matching merging customer without tools

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to match/merge Customer in order to remove duplicate in SQL.

I will explain with a small example.
I have a table Customer that contains firstname, lastname, ssn(not always populated) + phone number + email.

If I have 3 rules to identify a duplicate

```
same name,firstname,ssn 
same name,firstname,phone 
same name,firstname,email
```

sample :

```
custid, firstname,lastname,ssn,phone
1,billy,johns,null,020 6666 2222,null
2,billy,johns,111-225,020 6666 2222,null
3,billy,johns,111-225,020 6666 8888,test@gmail.com
4,billy,johns,null,020 6666 1111,test@gmail.com
5,eddy,barzoun,222-785,020 5252 5252
```

Based on the rules , Customer 1,2,3 and 4 are the same.

- 1 and 2 match on the phone number rule
- 2 and 3 match on the ssn rule
- 3 and 4 match on the email rule
- Customer 5 is alone.

Basically, for grouping on ssn,phone and email, I can use a sql analystical function or a group by.
Below the result:

```
custid, group_id_phon,group_id_ssn,group_id_email
1,1,1,1
2,1,2,2
3,2,2,3
4,3,3,3
5,4,4,4
```

How can I do to merge 1,2 ,3 and 4 in one unique customer.
I mean how can I consolidate(group) the Customer after applying the rules.
I'm kind of stuck.

I could have this  :

```
6,billy,johns,null,null,mail2@gmail.com
7,billy,johns,null,null,mail2@gmail.com
```

So 6 and 7 should be grouped and not linked to 1,2,3 and 4.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id, first_name, last_name, ssn, phone, email ) AS
SELECT 1, 'a', 'a', null, 1111, null  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'a', 'a',    1, 1111, null  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'a', 'a', null, 2222, null  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'a', 'a',    1, 2222, '1@1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'a', 'a', null, null, '1@1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'a', 'a', null, null, '2@2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'a', 'a', null, null, '2@2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 'b', 'b',    3, 3333, null  FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT id,
       (
         SELECT MIN( id )
         FROM   table_name s
         START WITH t.id = s.id
         CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
             PRIOR id <> id
         AND PRIOR first_name = first_name
         AND PRIOR last_name  = last_name
         AND ( PRIOR ssn = ssn OR PRIOR phone = phone OR PRIOR email = email )
       ) AS parent
FROM   table_name t
```

**Output**:

```
ID PARENT
-- ------
 1      1
 2      1
 3      1
 4      1
 5      1
 6      6
 7      6
 8      8
```

Comment: Couldn't even think about doing that

Comment: @Linus Updated for your additional test case.

Comment: @MT0 thanks it looks like it works, I will do more test. Could you explain a little bit ?

Comment: @Linus It just uses a correlated sub-query which starts from the given row and constructs a tree of reachable `id`s using your rules as the `CONNECT BY` clause of a hierarchical query - the correlated sub-query returns the minimum id found in the tree as the earliest instance of a matched row.

Comment: @Linus if you want to see how it does the search then replace `SELECT MIN(id)` with `SELECT LISTAGG( id, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ROWNUM )` and it will output all the ids in the matching group in the order it has traversed the tree for that id.

Comment: @MT0, do you think, there is a way to self code this ? and not use SQL ?

Comment: @Linus Please can you clarify your question? It is not clear what you are asking. If you have the data in an Oracle database then you are going to need to use SQL to get it out of the database.

Comment: @MT0 sure the data is in Oracle , assume I have 500 000 records, I guess It will take a while. I was wondering if I can split the work